# Django Q Filter - Too many Values to unpack

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to dynamicly create some filter criteria depending on the url query params.
For this I created a nested Django Q-Object which looks like:

```
query = <Q: (AND: (OR: region=30, region=39), name__endswith=Hannover, zip_code=30165)>
```

Now I want to pass this Q object to Model-Filter

```
Eort.objects.filter(query)
```

Thereby I get a ValueError : too many values to unpack (expected 2)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\felix\Documents\WZO\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\felix\Documents\WZO\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response     
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\felix\Documents\WZO\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view    
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\felix\Documents\WZO\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\felix\Documents\WZO\myenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\felix\Documents\WZO\myenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception       
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\felix\Documents\WZO\myenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\felix\Documents\WZO\myenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\felix\Documents\WZO\WZO\WZO_App\views.py", line 47, in get
    log.debug(Eort.objects.filter(eq))
  File "C:\Users\felix\Documents\WZO\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method      
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\felix\Documents\WZO\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 942, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\felix\Documents\WZO\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 962, in _filter_or_exclude   
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\felix\Documents\WZO\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 969, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\felix\Documents\WZO\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1358, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "C:\Users\felix\Documents\WZO\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1380, in _add_q
    split_subq=split_subq, check_filterable=check_filterable,
  File "C:\Users\felix\Documents\WZO\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1244, in build_filter    
    check_filterable=check_filterable,
  File "C:\Users\felix\Documents\WZO\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1380, in _add_q
    split_subq=split_subq, check_filterable=check_filterable,
  File "C:\Users\felix\Documents\WZO\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1244, in build_filter    
    check_filterable=check_filterable,
  File "C:\Users\felix\Documents\WZO\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1380, in _add_q
    split_subq=split_subq, check_filterable=check_filterable,
  File "C:\Users\felix\Documents\WZO\myenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1255, in build_filter    
    arg, value = filter_expr
```

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

This is how I created the Q-Object:

```
def or_operator(self, key, qlist):
        if qlist:
            result = Q()
            result.connector = Q.OR
            for i in qlist:
                if i == '':
                    continue
                if i[0] == '%' and i[-1] == '%':
                    result.add(Q('{0}__{1}={2}'.format(key, 'contains', i[1:-1])), Q.OR)
                elif i[0] == '%' and not i[-1] == '%':
                    result.add(Q('{0}__{1}={2}'.format(key, 'startswith', i[1:])), Q.OR)
                elif not i[0] == '%' and i[-1] == '%':
                    result.add(Q('{0}__{1}={2}'.format(key, 'endswith', i[:-1])), Q.OR)
                else:
                    result.add(Q('{0}={1}'.format(key, i)), Q.OR)
            return result 

query = Q()
query.connector = Q.AND
for key in params:
    if key in ['lat', 'lng', 'name', 'street', 'zip_code', 'city', 'region']:
        val = params.get(key, None).split(',')
        query.add(self.or_operator(key, val),Q.AND)
```

Comment: How did you construct this `Q` object?

Comment: Added the construction function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not work with `={2}`. A `Q` object is *not* a string of the form `foo=bar`, it is in essence a 2-tuple with as first element a string that is the "key" which is the field and optionally some lookups, and as second element a value, but that value can be a string, `datetime` object, etc. You thus construct the `Q` object with:

```
if i[0] == '%' and i[-1] == '%':
    result.add(Q((f'{key}__contains', i[1:-1])), Q.OR)
elif i[0] == '%' and not i[-1] == '%':
    result.add(Q((f'{key}__startswith', i[1:])), Q.OR)
elif not i[0] == '%' and i[-1] == '%':
    result.add(Q((f'{key}__endswith', i[:-1])), Q.OR)
else:
    result.add(Q((key, i)), Q.OR)
```

Comment: The Q Object looks a little different. <Q: (AND: (OR: (AND: region, 30), (AND: region, 39)), (AND: name, Hannover), (AND: zip_code, 30165))>

Comment: @aejsi5: did you *wrap* the values in a 2-tuple?

Comment: @aejsi5: based on the output, you wrote `Q(key, i)`, not `Q((key, i))`. You need to wrap the values in a 2-tuple, not pass these as individual items.